# Should one put the Apache configuration into apache conf or .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, configuration

I've been wondering what is more efficient to use either configuring for instance the mod_rewrite rules on the conf file for the virtual host (loads once and that is it), or put it in the `.htaccess` file on the directory itself, which as I understand loads and parses the file on every request . Is this wrong? Didn't I understand how Apache uses the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Apache tutorial on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) gives a good explanation on when you should and shouldn't use them and why. The short version is that you should generally only use them when you don't have access to the main Apache configuration files.

You should also use `AllowOverride None` which disables use of the .htaccess files as the server checks for them even if they don't exist. As the example in the tutorial gives, accessing `/www/htdocs/example,` checks for the following files each time:

```
/.htaccess
/www/.htaccess
/www/htdocs/.htaccess
/www/htdocs/example/.htaccess
```